# Parse private gcal JSON object with FullCalendar

Tags: json, fullcalendar, gcal

I wonder how I can provide FullCalendar a private gcal JSON feed. I know it is possible to provide a public gcal url, so I would like to either hack the gcal.js to manipulate the JSON object instead of the url, or manually transform my JSON object to comply with FullCalendar's JSON format.

So shall I follow one of this ways (and how) or is there any other alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think at this point the docu is a little bit *fuzzy*.

You do not need to publish your calendar, but you have to use the **private feed** of your calendar !

You can find the feed adress at the bottom of your calendar details, called **"Private Adress"** and then the **"XML"** button.

[image]