# FullCalendar with private google calendar event

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I currently using google calendar on my website with the iframe you can insert. I tested Fullcalendar and I like what you can do with it.

But I would like to do same as the embed calendar, I would like to be able to create private event (not calendar, events). The sharing settings of the calendar is on public, but when using chrome, you can log with your google account and with the embed calendar you can see private event (if you have access to the calendar).

Is that possible with Fullcalendar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure out how to connect via OAUTH and get the private event when you are authentified.

By clicking on a button, you can connect to a google account (If already connected in browser, no button will appear and you will be log automaticly).

I follow [this google example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#Authexample)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

   var clientId = '<your-client-id>';
   var apiKey = '<your-api-key>';
   var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

   function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
   }

   function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
   }

   function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
     authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';    
     makeApiCall();
    } else {
     authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
     authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
     GeneratePublicCalendar();
    }
   }

   function handleAuthClick(event) {            
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
   }
   
   
   // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
   function makeApiCall() {

    // Step 4: Load the Google+ API
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3').then(function() {
      // Step 5: Assemble the API request
       var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
       'calendarId': '<your-calendar-id(The @gmail.com>'
      });
      
      // Step 6: Execute the API request
      request.then(function(resp) {

       var eventsList = [];
       var successArgs;
       var successRes;

       if (resp.result.error) {
        reportError('Google Calendar API: ' + data.error.message, data.error.errors);
       }
       else if (resp.result.items) {
        $.each(resp.result.items, function(i, entry) {
         var url = entry.htmlLink;

         // make the URLs for each event show times in the correct timezone
         //if (timezoneArg) {
         //    url = injectQsComponent(url, 'ctz=' + timezoneArg);
         //}

         eventsList.push({
          id: entry.id,
          title: entry.summary,
          start: entry.start.dateTime || entry.start.date, // try timed. will fall back to all-day
          end: entry.end.dateTime || entry.end.date, // same
          url: url,
          location: entry.location,
          description: entry.description
         });
        });

        // call the success handler(s) and allow it to return a new events array
        successArgs = [ eventsList ].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); // forward other jq args
        successRes = $.fullCalendar.applyAll(true, this, successArgs);
        if ($.isArray(successRes)) {
         return successRes;
        }
       }

       if(eventsList.length > 0)
       {
                              // Here create your calendar but the events options is :
                              //fullcalendar.events: eventsList (Still looking for a methode that remove current event and fill with those news event without recreating the calendar.
                              
                            }
                          return eventsList;
       
       }, function(reason) {
      console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
       });
    });
   }

function GeneratePublicCalendar(){  
  // You need a normal fullcalendar with googleApi when user isn't logged
  
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    googleCalendarApiKey: '<your-key>',      
      ...
    });  
}
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

And in your google api console, make sure in API & Auth -> ID

OAuth Javascript origin is set properly (Like http://localhost
https://localhost if you are working on a local website)

Leave Redirection and API referent empty.

Answer (score 2):

Fullcalendar is a front-end solution only. Logging into a google account and any other authentication isn't part of it.

That said, it can be [connected to a google calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/), but only if it's a public google calendar. If you want to interface it to a private google calendar, you would have to build in that functionality.

If you can get the gcal events with JS and handle authentication, getting them into FullCalendar is easy. But that first part takes a few steps. Take a look at the google calendar api docs for instruction.

Comment: Yes, I made a Fullcalendar and it's easy and really nice. But what I'm looking is for a modification on gcal.js to handle authentification and be able to collect private event if possible. If you event is private and your disponibility is to busy, Fullcalendar load the event as an undefined event. I would like to change this undefined event if you're logged.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946993/parse-private-gcal-json-object-with-fullcalendar you can just use the private feed of your calendar. I have no idea how authentication works when doing that though. Maybe try the private feed but have it fallback if it fails.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, let me know and I will probably delete my answer since it kind of misses the point.

Comment: Your answer isn't bad. It pointing on the fact that fullcalendar is really front-end and I know it. But I would like to know how to handle auth and get calendar access like the embed doing.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau What happens when you use the "Private Adress" instead of the public one?

Comment: @slicetoad I think I found the answer. I would need to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl), to get user access token and after using this token to call the google api (Like gcal.js already do) but I need to figure out how to get the token and put it into the api request.

Comment: [Here the step by step example](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?code=4/gU8hbMfAxwB-OFOD0hDoVuw9NwWjODA3rgGIvT74NlY.YrjhjISv-5YeJvIeHux6iLaF-8N4lgI)

Comment: When you get it working, add the whole solution as an answer. I don't think there is a complete example online yet.

Comment: Have you managed to create events using FullCalendar?  I am struggling trying to make it work using your example above but no success. can you post full answer please..

Comment: @Skwashy Create gcal events? No, I haven't, but I don't use FC with gcal so I haven't tried either. Post it as a question (including what you've tried) and see if someone can help.

Comment: JavaScript is also a backend language... NodeJS