# My FullCalendar cannot create a Google Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have a `Google Calendar` sharing a specific calendar all set working with `FullCalendar`, but I am unable to create an event to my `Google calendar` from

**FullCalendar code is:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    allDay: true,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: false,

    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    dayClick: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var title = prompt('Create an event:');
        if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay
                },
                true // make the event "stick"
            );
        }
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },

    googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyA2obQBQF_npk4rq-nU-X5kYfIkuWsBJkY',
    events: {
        googleCalendarId: 'efxpromedia.com_jvm3li2c2jva0f9hd89lt5hikg@group.calendar.google.com',

    },
    eventClick: function(event) {
        // opens events in a popup window
        window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=800,height=700');
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        return false;
    },
}); //CALENDAR
}
```

To read the events and edit them it works fine, the gcal.js is the most updated and the [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an google event using `fullcalendar` its only used to display events fetched from your google calendar. In order to save events to your google calendar you will have to use [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). And For this you will be requiring an backend programing language, Please follow the link and you will find out the solution.

Comment: Have you managed to get it to work with FullCalendar using the API?

Comment: yes i do have implemented it and works like a charm, i have used php at the backend by the way. Give it a try it works, and if you are stuck somewhere share here we are here to help

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: it was for admin pannel not for general users the project was about scheduling and routing management which uses two google API's calendar and map. which programing language are you using?

Comment: Doing it all in Business Catalyst using Javascript basically I am trying to create the same thing you did, but I just want to create an event using sort of an iframe once i click on an event from the admin calendar

Comment: Still looking for an answer... I have seen some guys succeeding with PHP but I will learn it in a different life! found [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242742/fullcalendar-with-private-google-calendar-event)  and I am testing it with  a few mods please let me know if you see the light of it.

Comment: start an bounty on it you might get a solution & i have achieved it using php there might be another solution as well that i am unaware of. Keep on searching & if i come accross any solution i will post it here.