# Fullcalendar + Private google calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I m using full calendar for a web app project and I sync it with google calendar of my client, but for the moment only public calendar.

Is there any way to sync with a private calendar ?

***Note :*** We use 0auth to identify and sync with Google account.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it would work with private calendar using the correct authorization.

## [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth#OAuth2Authorizing)

> All requests to the Google Calendar API must be authorized by an authenticated user.

Here is a sample create by [Alexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28328195/5995040):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var clientId = '<your-client-id>';
            var apiKey = '<your-api-key>';
            var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

            function handleClientLoad() {
                gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
                window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
            }

            function checkAuth() {
                gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
            }

            function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
                var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
                
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';          
                    makeApiCall();
                } else {
                    authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
                    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
                    GeneratePublicCalendar();
                }
            }

            function handleAuthClick(event) {            
                gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
                return false;
            }
            
            
            // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
            function makeApiCall() {

                // Step 4: Load the Google+ API
                gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3').then(function() {
                  // Step 5: Assemble the API request
                      var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                            'calendarId': '<your-calendar-id(The @gmail.com>'
                        });
                  
                        // Step 6: Execute the API request
                        request.then(function(resp) {

                            var eventsList = [];
                            var successArgs;
                            var successRes;

                            if (resp.result.error) {
                                reportError('Google Calendar API: ' + data.error.message, data.error.errors);
                            }
                            else if (resp.result.items) {
                                $.each(resp.result.items, function(i, entry) {
                                    var url = entry.htmlLink;

                                    // make the URLs for each event show times in the correct timezone
                                    //if (timezoneArg) {
                                    //    url = injectQsComponent(url, 'ctz=' + timezoneArg);
                                    //}

                                    eventsList.push({
                                        id: entry.id,
                                        title: entry.summary,
                                        start: entry.start.dateTime || entry.start.date, // try timed. will fall back to all-day
                                        end: entry.end.dateTime || entry.end.date, // same
                                        url: url,
                                        location: entry.location,
                                        description: entry.description
                                    });
                                });

                                // call the success handler(s) and allow it to return a new events array
                                successArgs = [ eventsList ].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); // forward other jq args
                                successRes = $.fullCalendar.applyAll(true, this, successArgs);
                                if ($.isArray(successRes)) {
                                    return successRes;
                                }
                            }

                            if(eventsList.length > 0)
                            {
                              // Here create your calendar but the events options is :
                              //fullcalendar.events: eventsList (Still looking for a methode that remove current event and fill with those news event without recreating the calendar.
                              
                            }
                          return eventsList;
                            
                      }, function(reason) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
                      });
                });
            }

function GeneratePublicCalendar(){  
  // You need a normal fullcalendar with googleApi when user isn't logged
  
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    googleCalendarApiKey: '<your-key>',      
      ...
    });  
}
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

---

Or

## [Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth#perform-google-apps-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority)

> In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access users data without any manual authorization on their part. In Google Apps domains, the domain administrator can grant to third party applications domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred as domain-wide delegation of authority. To delegate authority this way, domain administrators can use service accounts with OAuth 2.0.
>
> For additional detailed information, see [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in the backend with php, use the google php client library to get the events and then put it into fullcalendar. This way, it works.